# Codeigniter "News section" tutorial issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with the URI.
I've tried to look through the post, but couldn't see the answer.

Tutorial can be found here:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Basically I replicated all and it works fine, but there one think where I don't
know whether is my browser or I miss-configured something.

In the "views/news/index.php" I have the following code as per tutorial:

```
<h2><? echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
<div id="main">
    <? echo $news_item['text']?>
</div>
<p>[b]<a href="news/<? echo $news_item['slug']?>">View Article</a>[/b]</p>
```

Now the problem is that when I look into the source html on my browser I see the link as:

View Article

Which I assume is correct.
But when I click on, it points me to:

localhost/CI/index.php/news/news/firstnews

As you can see the "news" is repeated twice in the URI.
It looks like the browser is simply appending the href value to the URI that is open,
instead of cleaning it down to index.php and add it there.

I tried to remove the "news" bit from the href value and it works fine.

I am using Chome if that makes any difference.

Is that my misstake? Or this is just an error in the tutorial?

Comment: I had the same issue.... I think it's a typo.  I changed `<a href="news/` to `<a href="view/` and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Igor, I think, that's a tutorial's mistake and you need add / in the href attribute.
E.g.

```
<a href="/news/<? echo $news_item['slug']?>">View Article</a>
```

Besides, you should use URL Helper - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

P.s. there is a chance that you don't tune .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid this kind of mistakes I often use `base_url()` when writing down the links. Like this:

```
<?php echo anchor(base_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']),View article); ?>
```

Note that I use the the `anchor()` & `base_url()` functions of the [URL helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html). More info at:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a mistake in the CI tutorial.

---

First of all it's recommended to use the `site_url()` function to help generate the news slug URL.

You do this by adding `$this->load->helper('url');` to the `__construct()` of your News controller in **controllers/news.php**

Then change your link URL in your **views/news/index.php** to `<?php echo site_url('news/' . $news_item['slug']); ?>`

---

The most crucial mistake is that throughout your current files you're populating `$data['news']` while the rest of your functions are looking at `$data[‘news_item’]`

You should change these (two) variables in **views/news/view.php** and the (three) variables in the `view()` function in **controller/news.php**

After reloading the page, that should do it! For the full discussion on the CI forums check the following link: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/209349/

Answer (score 0):

For me i changed

```
   $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
```

to:

```
   $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
```

and that works fine, now

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I found this git repo [github.com/Crias/tutorial-codeigniter-news](https://github.com/Crias/tutorial-codeigniter-news) which contains source code for the default codeigniter tutorial.

Now you don't need to type (or copy-paste) it again to make the tutorial works.