# CodeIgniter and jQuery Mobile 1.2

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-mobile

I have a CodeIgniter web app I'm trying to convert (UPDATE: I'm trying to overlay the JQM UI) [to a jQuery Mobile app]. I'm having problems setting up tabs that link to my CodeIgniter controllers.

This is the code in my "header.php" view - inside a `<div data-role="page"></div>`. This is called by a main controller, which works fine. Now, the problem: I am trying to set up my jQuery Mobile navbar tabs to call a new controller called inbox.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>
          <a href='<?php echo base_url()."inbox"?>' data-ajax="false">Inbox</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without jQuery Mobile, the link works fine and triggers the Inbox CodeIgniter controller, but with JQM enabled in my header.php view, I get a "404 Not Found" page when I click on the Inbox tab.

Update - this jQuery code in the html head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/all-mobile.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/logo.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/logo.png" />

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Update 2: If I insert this code in t.js to remove the automatic ajax links:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

and my new head html code is now:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/t.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

… the jQuery Mobile does load up but the "inbox" link still generates a 404 page **by CI**.

UPDATE 3: I determined it's a problem with something local.  When I upload the CI code and the new jQuery Mobile scripts to my web server, the tab linking to my inbox.php controller **does** in fact work!  Does anyone know why it doesn't work on my local machine using MAMP?  Now, it appears that I can't develop and test locally with this configuration.  Is there a fix?

Looking at allowCrossDomainPages at jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html I added $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; to the jQuery initialization but it did not help the localhost server running MAMP serve up the inbox.php controller - still 404.

**UPDATE 4: PROBLEM SOLVED**.  It turns out there was a problem in the hidden file .htaccess.  To rewrite the URI, it contains a "RewriteBase /myapp-mobile/"; this directory became incorrect when I moved it over to the new folder under htdocs.

Comment: CI is server-side and jQuery Mobile is client-side.  You can't just _"convert"_ one to the other.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to keep all the server-side functionality, but add the jQuery Mobile overlay structure.  I'm loading jQuery and jQuery Mobile in the header.php view now, instead of my custom CSS.  And I'm hoping to get the fixed tabs at the bottom etc.  Then it will have jQm UI with CI backend.  What I don't get is why my CI site works fine with mysite/inbox (it loads the "inbox.php controller) but now it's 404. Do you see any issues with that?

Comment: What is the result of `<?php echo base_url()."inbox"?>`?  Then ask yourself how/why the mobile browser with jQ Mobile should handle that any differently than the desktop browser.

Comment: I see the result when I hover the tab: http://localhost:8888/myapp/inbox  . It's the same link that gets created in my CI app so I want it to load the index.php controller.  I added the data-ajax="false" so that it would load "externally" but I think I'm missing something

Comment: Then show your jQuery code.  Maybe you have some click handlers that are messing this up.

Comment: I updated with the code above to show my jQuery includes but I have no other jQuery code in there right now…I did have some in a footer.php view but I've taken it out…that's why I'm stumped.  I even replaced the data-ajax="false" with rel="external" and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You have no custom jQuery?  Weird.  What could jQuery Mobile be doing to the click?

Comment: It seems to be a basic problem but perplexing.  If I remove the rel="external", then jQuery Mobile throws up a spinner, then a yellow pop up with "Error Loading Page".  It's now this:
<li><a href='<?php echo base_url()."inbox"?>'>Inbox</a></li>

Comment: [See the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/globalconfig.html). `ajaxEnabled (boolean, default: true): jQuery Mobile will automatically handle link clicks and form submissions through Ajax, when possible. If false, url hash listening will be disabled as well, and urls will load as regular http requests.`  ~  Looks like it treats all links as ajax requests unless you specifically set that option(s) to `false` within the `mobileinit` function, which you don't have.

Comment: Also:  [_"Working with jQuery Mobile's **Auto-initialization** - Unlike other jQuery projects, such as jQuery and jQuery UI, jQuery Mobile **automatically applies many markup enhancements as soon as it loads** (long before document.ready event fires)."_](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/globalconfig.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me.  Check your console for JavaScript errors.  You were supposed to create a function using the `mobileinit` event [as per the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/globalconfig.html), and then within that, set the `ajaxEnabled` option to `false` using `.extend`.

Comment: Right… thanks.  I had a mistake calling the t.js - fixed now.  The jQuery Mobile works now for the main page but the inbox tab still produces a 404, which must be created by CI.  It might be a problem with CI….I'm going to look at that next.

Comment: That's good... now it's just a simple issue with your base url or path then.  I'm going to post my original suggestion as a solution below.

Comment: I **think** you're right but I copied my complete functional CI configuration over to the new folder as a base and then started to add the jQuery Mobile.  It's still weird that CI is throwing a new 404.  I don't know why I'd have to change anything in my base path url, so I'll continue investigating.

Comment: Something to note:  When using the stock CI demo/tutorial, I was getting 404 errors in Explorer, but not in other browsers.  It was how IE was handling the relative paths with respect to what it thought was the base url.  I had to change my path in the view to absolute in order to get the demo to work in all browsers.  Maybe something similar here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333641/codeigniter-news-section-tutorial-issue

Comment: I'm fortunately using Safari on a Mac.  Still strange that I've used dozens of base_url() links in the working CI app but now something's broken.

Comment: Note that in my CI config.php, I have the following: 
$config['base_url'] = ''; and it functions fine.

Comment: I posted an UPDATE 3.  On the web, the link does work.  The problem is with a local link.  Is it something to do with cross-scripting on the same local server?

Comment: Looking at allowCrossDomainPages at  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html I added  $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; to the jQuery initialization but it did not help me locally.

Comment: Doubtful. "Cross domain" means you're accessing URL's on another domain.

Comment: Go back and [read the last thing I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333641/codeigniter-news-section-tutorial-issue).  I know you are not using IE... that's not the point.  Read it carefully, and verify that your URL's are being interpreted correctly by the browser.  Also see how [the second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12345855/594235) is using `base_url()` differently than you.

Comment: Reviewed the postings and as far as I can tell, the link is being created correctly.  I've pinpointed it to the following:  In the local MAMP development, I get a "404" from CI; when I upload to a web server, the CodeIgniter recognizes the URL fine and serves up the page…very strange.  I'm wondering...Is there some kind of conflict with CI and JqM only locally?

Comment: Update - problem solved.  It turns out there was a problem in the hidden file .htaccess.  To rewrite the URI, it contains a "RewriteBase /myapp-mobile/"; this directory became incorrect when I moved it over to the new folder under htdocs.  MANY THANKS for the help in pinpointing this bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the documentation:](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/globalconfig.html)

> **Working with jQuery Mobile's Auto-initialization** - Unlike other jQuery projects, such as jQuery and jQuery UI, **jQuery Mobile
>   automatically applies many markup enhancements as soon as it loads**
>   (long before document.ready event fires).

And...

> **ajaxEnabled (boolean, default: true):** jQuery Mobile **will automatically handle link clicks and form submissions through Ajax**,
>   when possible. If false, url hash listening will be disabled as well,
>   and urls will load as regular http requests.

Looks like it treats all links as ajax requests unless you specifically set that option to `false` within the `mobileinit` function, which you don't yet have.

Use this function below to force jQuery mobile to treat all links as normal `http` requests.

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    // other options to enable on intialization
});
```